# Ionic: Failed to install app

Tags: ionic-framework

I just built a simple app, and generated APK using following command:

```
ionic cordova  build android
```

I downloaded this APK to my mobile, and trued to install. It was showing following error:

> Failed to install app

Please help me.

**My ionic version:3.9.2**

**Cordova:7.0.1**

**npm:3.10.10**

**Node: 6.11.0**

**Angular: 5.0.0**

**Typescript: 2.4.2**

Comment: try running "ionic cordova run android"

Comment: do you have the production version of that app or any other version of that app already installed on your device....if yes...then remove them first and then try to install your apk.

Comment: No, I don't have any version installed on my mobile. I'm installing for the very first time. And, I can't run "ionic Cordova run android", as I don't want to connect my mobile to PC. I want APK, so that I can share to others.

Comment: check if your config.xml has the correct packname.

Answer (score 0):

Check the config file. I think same id used for install app. Change the id for config file like below:

```
<widget id="com.ionic.app" version="1.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

Comment: My config.xml is as follows: <widget id="com.ionic.starter" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">